# convert factor variable of gender into numeric for KNN in R

Tags: r

I wanted to use KNN algorithm to create model to predict the wage is either <=50k usd or >50k usd based on the gender and education level. Is it possible to convert gender as numeric value like (male,female,non-binary) to (1,2,3)? Same goes to education level (college, master, phd) to (1,2,3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be tricky depending on your data, so here is an option using `as.numeric` like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(gender = factor(c("male", "female", "non-binary")),
                 level = factor(c("college", "master", "phd")))

str(df)
#> 'data.frame':    3 obs. of  2 variables:
#>  $ gender: Factor w/ 3 levels "female","male",..: 2 1 3
#>  $ level : Factor w/ 3 levels "college","master",..: 1 2 3
df$gender <- as.numeric(df$gender)
str(df)
#> 'data.frame':    3 obs. of  2 variables:
#>  $ gender: num  2 1 3
#>  $ level : Factor w/ 3 levels "college","master",..: 1 2 3
df
#>   gender   level
#> 1      2 college
#> 2      1  master
#> 3      3     phd
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>